# How do I write a super-logarithm in a graphing application such as Desmos?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, tetration

I'm trying to plug in a super-logarithm (inverse function of tetration) in Desmos

Wikipedia's definition though is defined implicitly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm

Not sure how to translate that into Desmos. I know I can manually plot the points of the function, but looking for a better way

Comment: Use Wolfram alpha?

Comment: How would I graph it in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I thought it'd have resources.. but- https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8owg4i2fyi